# One of Neil Gaiman's Riddles

Tags: riddle, word

> I turn my head, and you may go where you want.
>   I turn it again, and you'll stay till you rot.
>
> I have no face, but I live or die.
>   By my crooked teeth,
>
> Who am I?

This riddle was originally from Neil Gaiman's book *Neverwhere*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> a key.

I turn my head, and you may go where you want.

> You can turn a key to unlock a door.

I turn it again, and you'll stay till you rot.

> You can also turn a key to lock a door.

I have no face, but I live or die.
By my crooked teeth,

> A key has "teeth" that fits its lock. If the teeth are damaged, the key will not work.